# chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, chroot

I am trying to do a chroot as a certain user. For one user it works, for other users it does not, and I have no idea what is going on.

My `/etc/passwd` in the chroot directory looks like this (relevant part):

```
test0:x:1000:1000:test0:/home/test:/bin/bash
test1:x:1001:1001:test1:/home/test:/bin/bash
```

- `sudo chroot --userspec=test0 chroot_dir/ /bin/bash --login` works well
- `sudo chroot --userspec=test1 chroot_dir/ /bin/bash --login` says `chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: Permission denied`
- details of `/bin/bash` in chroot: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 455188 Sep 19 08:58`, where `user` is my username in the system.

Any ideas why user `test1` does not work? If you need any more information, just please ask, I will put them in. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `chroot` (and no user namespaces, which is the case here), the directories and files necessary to run the command you give to `chroot` need to be accessible to the user you specify. This includes:

- the chroot’s root;
- `bin` and `bin/bash` in the chroot;
- `lib` and any libraries therein used by `bash`, if any (`ldd bin/bash` will tell you what they are);
- when `bash` gets going, `home/test` and any startup scripts (`.bashrc` etc. if necessary).

Running `chmod -R 777` obviously fixes all this; you can use more restrictive permissions, as long as user id 1001 can read and execute the appropriate files. `chmod -R 755 bin lib` and `chmod 755 .` would allow `bash` to start.